# How do I select multiple layers/groups with mouse's dragging?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, selections

I have in the workspace some objects. Some are grouped, and are near.
I'd like to make a selection of them with click/mouse drag, instead of shift-click selecting each of them (they are somethings like 30 objects, in a small range).

I don't want to make a new group with them.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Group Selection Tool** and drag around all the objects you want to select

[image]

> **Group Selection tool**
>
> Lets you select an object within a group, a single group within multiple groups, or a set of groups within the artwork. Each additional click adds all objects from the next group in the hierarchy.

*Source [helpx.adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html)*

Comment: Any shortcut to enable this feature with keyboard?

Comment: I updated the other answer with the shortcuts