# Is it possible to "temporarily" select a sub-level of a group for single edits?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

Let say I've a group of 4 layers.

Once I select it with mouse, it selects the whole "group": every edit applies to all sub layers (such as move, drag, resize, and so on).

Is it possible (without moving a sub layer outside the group, or to select it with the layer panel at the left) to just select a sub-level for further edits?

Later, once I click out and again on the group, it selects all again.

i.e. "temporarily" select a sub-level of a group for single edits, with mouse, directly clicking on the layer, or some other command? like ctrl+click?

Answer (score 1):

From the **Layers Panel**, open the group and click the **Target Layer** icon (the circle).
Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more than a path or group layer.

[image]

Using tools, press <kbd>A</kbd> to activate the **Direct Selection Tool** and click each object from the group holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>

Comment: Yes, but as I said, can I do it directly with mouse over the layer? With a "bypass" command maybe? I already know what you suggest...

Comment: In that case, your question is an exactly dup of [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/125751/120647)

Comment: Uhm. Using "A" on CC2019 already did the selection really. I don't Need alt + shift! But: once selected, I Need to switch to V and the resize the object (height for example). Otherwise, it rescale both width and height. Also for you?

Comment: @markzzz It's also possible to enter [isolation mode](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html) by double clicking a group to enter it - then you can select what you want, move it etc., then double click outside the group to exit isolation mode.